# convert SVG code to format to attach to user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, stimulusjs

Essentially, in my app users can create a custom svg element using js (stimulus).

My user.rb model has:

```
  has_one_attached :picture
```

in my attach_image_controller.js I can access the svg code:

```
<svg> 
  <-- blah blah >
</svg>
```

What is the best way to transform this code into a format that can be attached in my user_controller.rb?

I have tried turning the code into a blob and creating an object url, but I haven't been able to then attach it to a user (see below attempt)

```
attach_image_controller.js

var testsvg = `<svg> 
  <-- blah blah >
</svg>`;
var blob = new Blob([testsvg], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log(url); // returns: blob:http://localhost:3000/15107c0d-b794-4be6-a1e0-2cf9e8f49174 and results in routing error
// As there is a routing error, this url can't be used as per  below
```

and then when passed to the user_controller.rb:

```
user_controller.rb
@url = params[:url] 
@user = current_user
file = URI.open(@url[5..-1])
@user.picture.attach(
  io: file,
  filename: @url[5..-1],
  content_type: 'image/svg+xml')
```

Edit:

To make things more complicated, in some cases, users have the ability to upload and attach an image, or generate a svg code that renders in the DOM, but I want to be able to attach both the SVG code and the uploaded image.

Comment: use  gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.13', '>= 1.13.6' , link: https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

The typical use case for attachments is when we wish to associate an uploaded file (often an image, e.g. jpg) with a model.

However the svg is an html snippet, it's a string comprised of a single html element (`<svg>... </svg>`). So you might consider simply including it as a string column in your User model. Remember, though, that you need to declare it html_safe before it will render correctly. So if you are using erb, you'll have `<%= user.svg_image.html_safe %>`.